# Реализация наград и рейтинга пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Вопрос довольно абстрактный:

Стоит задача реализации рейтинга и наград пользователей сайта. За определенные действия на сайте пользователь получает награду и определенное количество рейтинга. Приведу примеры наград:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: как грамотно реализовать такой функционал?

Вижу 2 способа:

1. при определенных действиях пользователя определять, выполнены ли условия для получения той или иной награды, запоминать в базе, что этот пользователь получил награду, а рейтинг пересчитывать исходя из того, какие награды он получил (будет таблица `rewards` с полями id, name, icon, rating), просто складывать значения поля `rating`
2. для каждого пользователя в таблице `users` хранить текущее значение рейтинга и наращивать это поле по мере получения новых наград

И вижу здесь одну проблему:

допустим пользователь получил награду, например, за 100-й лайк к своей записи (в БД создалась запись о том что данный пользователь имеет эту награду), потом один из тех кто поставил лайк убирает его, и уже становится не 100, а 99 лайков. Как отслеживать подобные ситуации?

И, опять же, по примеру выше, в какой момент лучше проверять выполнение условий этой награды? Можно такие проверки делать каждый раз, когда кто-то ставит лайк (делать запрос в БД и проверять, нет ли в списке его записей такой, которую лайкнули не менее 100 раз. Но может есть другие, более правильные, варианты?

Буду рад любому совету или замечанию по данному вопросу, заранее благодарю! ;)

Comment: Ну это не простая система, логику так словами всю и не опишешь, трактат получится. Конкретно по вашему вопросу объедините начало первого пункта со вторым и будет уже адекватнее.

Comment: Описываемые процессы - это тот случай, когда оптимизация требует накопления и хранения избыточных (переопределённых) данных - т.е. проведения предрасчёта и хранения его результатов. Небольшая потеря точности, дающая оперативность и снижение интегральной нагрузки. Пример же про сотню лайков - ниачём, поскольку оперативный подсчёт производится только для одного пользователя.

Comment: Собственно я не могу определиться, в какой момент и как часто нужно выполнять перерасчёт? Допустим мне нужно отобразить на сайте 10 пользователей с указанием рейтинга каждого, я просто делаю запрос в таблицу users в которой уже хранятся значения рейтинга каждого пользователя, но как часто пересчитывать рейтинг чтобы и систему не нагружать и поддерживать актуальность данных?

Comment: У вас же не real-time архитектура. Поэтому сильно то и не нагрузишь. Учитывая что вы пишите на php.

Comment: Если кто-то уже реализовывал подобный функционал, попробуйте описать всю эту структуру вкратце: каким образов и в какой момент проверять выполнены ли условия той или иной награды? Стоит ли хранить в БД текущий рейтинг пользователя или лучше каждый раз пересчитывать суммарный рейтинг уже полученных наград?

Comment: Для обновления рейтинга необходимо в index.php  прописать функцию ежедневной проверки которая будет проверять был ли обновлен рейтинг сегодня по времени. Время и Дата обновления заносится в базу функция в index.php проверяет время и если дата за вчерашний день то рейтинг обновляется если рейтинг сегодня уже обновился то функция его не трогает, так же если требуется обновление каждый час то аналогично.В самой бд необходима таблица которая будет хранить время - дату  пред. обновления. Нагрузки не будет. Рейтинг будет корректно обновляться

Comment: Не понял в чем заключается проблема? Ведь можно создать таблицу с метриками (id пользователя, количество авторизаций на сайте, количество отзывов, количество комментариев), 
и написать триггеры которые будут выполняться и менять метрики, при этих если условия выполнили то присылать push пользователю и добавлять в таблицу наград награду для пользователя.

Comment: @users, вот это уже что-то ;) не плохая идея, можете оформить это в виде ответа? не зря же я награду назначал ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Предлагаю такую структуру данных:

#### Для метрик:

Создать таблицу с метриками:

```
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| users_id | metric_x | ... | metric_y |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
|        1 |       10 | ... |      310 |
|        2 |       34 | ... |      103 |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

Либо в более нормализованном виде (но за 1 запрос будет уже не строка, а список):

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| users_id |       name |    value |
+----------+------------+----------+
|        1 |          1 |       10 |
|        1 |          2 |      310 |
|        2 |          1 |       34 |
|        2 |          2 |      103 |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

#### Для достижений:

Ссылка на пользователя и на достижение (можно в список достижений уже поместить фото, описание, и если достижений не много можно хранить их в массиве)

```
+----------+-----------------+
| users_id |  achievement_id |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 |               1 |
|        1 |               2 |
|        2 |               1 |
|        3 |               8 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

#### Таблица с достижениями (многоточие означают информацию о достижении):

и поле `metric_id` говорят какая метрика и `value` и когда достижение будет выполнено, но у этого примера есть ограничения его скорей всего будет сложно использовать например для достижений по 2 метрикам или достижениям который зависят от достижений и скорей всего стоит отказать от достижений или объединить их с метриками.

```
+----+-----+------------+-------+
| id | ... |  metric_id | value |
+----+-----+------------+-------+
|  1 | ... |          1 |   300 |
|  2 | ... |          2 |   200 |
|  3 | ... |          1 |    50 |
+----+-----+------------+-------+
```

#### И тригеры которые будут вызываться при нужных действиях:

И пример псевдокода (использую нормализованную таблицу для метрик):

```
public function trigger_update($user_id, $metric_id, $metric_value, $achievement) { 
    $sql = "UPDATE metric SET value = value + {$metric_value} 
            WHERE users_id = {$user_id} AND name = {$metric_id}";

    // выполнения запроса и получения элемента 
    $metic_value = sql_query($sql).commit();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM achievement WHERE id = {$achievement} AND metric_id = {$metric_id} AND value >= ${value}";
    if (sql_query($sql).commit() !== Null){          

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users_achievement (users_id, achievement_id) VALUES ({$user_id}, {$achievement});"

        // и да, нужен индекс что-бы записи были уникальны 
        // и тут нужны обработка исключений или select что-бы нормально реагировать на то что у человека уже есть данное достижение. 
        sql_query($sql).commit();
        push_user($user_id, $metric_value);  // и метод уведомления
    }
}
```

#### p.s.

И достижения можно хранить в массиве и их условие, и не использовать для этих целей базу, из плюсов нет лишних запросов в БД, из минусов нет возможности быстро их менять.

Comment: От души, чувак! :) Буду разбираться, пока вроде всё понятно